# Sending psql variable into shell

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'd like to send variable in psql into shell to do some tricky things with it there and use the result in psql again. See:

```
\set ENVIR `echo :HOST | cut -f2 -d-`
\echo :ENVIR
```

However, the psql variable seems to be not interpolating in backticks as I would expect: shell's `echo :HOST` gives just `:HOST`. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\setenv` to export the psql variable to the shell:

```
\set HOST 'the-host-name'
\setenv HOST :HOST
\set ENVIR `echo $HOST | cut -f2 -d-`
\echo :ENVIR
```

produces:

```
host
```

#### Edit

Of course, your example can be done with postgres string functions, with no need for shelling out.